# How to create a Rank Column with recurring rank number? (Excel)

Tags: excel

I would be happy if you would like to check the picture bellow first so you might clearly and directly  understand my question.

I want to generate a field that ranking every state according to its assigned region

These are my inputs:

```
|    Region    |       State     |
      West         California
      West         Arizona
      West         Washington 
      East         New York
      East         Florida
      East         North Carolina
      South        Texas
      South        Louisiana
      South        Alabama
```

I would like to generate the "Rank State" field

```
|    Region    |       State     |       Rank State   | 
      West         California                1
      West         Arizona                   2 
      West         Washington                3
      East         New York                  1
      East         Florida                   2 
      East         North Carolina            3
      South        Texas                     1
      South        Louisiana                 2 
      South        Alabama                   3
```

the question is: what calculation or method can do the "rank state" column/field?

I'd be Happy to accept excel solutions if it is possible :)

---

[image]

Comment: Have a list of states with the respective rank number then use vlookup().

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way I see it, you want to count how many states above or including the selected one are in the same region?

Assuming 'Region' is Column A (in excel)
in row 2 in the Rank column, paste:

```
=COUNTIF($A$2:$A2, $A2)
```

Then autofill it down the column (double-click or drag the little green square at the bottom right of the selected cell)

Comment: If 'Region' isn't in column A, replace `A` in the above with whatever column it is in.